# AS3 change lineStyle of existing line

Tags: actionscript-3, line, draw, linestyle, coords

im drawing a line from 0,0 to 100,100

im using this to modify the linestyle:

```
draw_line.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000);
```

That line is now of 1 thickness.

Is there anyway i can change the thickness of the line to say 10, but without redrawing the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible with the way the flash player works, you must redraw the line. Or use some kind of library that automatically redraws it for you (for example a Line object in the Flex 4 Framework)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
draw_line.scaleX = 10;
```

Not exactly the same, but could possibly work under certain circumstances.